# Is there a build-in ordinal sequence vector in R?

Tags: r

I need a long ordinal sequence vector in R. As a simple example of what I want:

```
OS <- c("First","Second","Third")
```

Is there a build-in vector like that?

Comment: Not built-in, because it'd have to be part of the locale.

Comment: @alistaire Make sense. Thanks!

Comment: You could pull it out of [Unicode CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-rbnf/blob/master/rbnf/en.json) maybe, though that may be as much work as typing out yourself, depending on how far you need to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from `library(english)`

```
ordinal(1:5)
# [1] first  second third  fourth fifth
```

Answer (score 2):

I googled "R cardinal numbers" and got to the [vignette for the toOrdinal package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/toOrdinal/vignettes/toOrdinal.html), but unfortunately it doesn't actually get you words.

```
library(toOrdinal)
sapply(1:5,toOrdinal)
## [1] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "4th" "5th"
```

The docs say

> convert_to: OPTIONAL. Output type that provided 'cardinal_number' is
>             converted into. Default is 'ordinal_number' which refers to
>             the 'cardinal_number' followed by the appropriate ordinal
>             indicator. **Additional options planned include 'ordinal_word'.**

so maybe this will eventually do what you want ...